# Use regular and light font in the same document

Tags: fonts, pdftex

Hey I am using the font Chivo Light. Since the bold version of the font appears too thick for me I also want to use Chivo Regular within the same document. So Chivo Light should be my regular font and Chivo Regular should be my bold font.

With
`\usepackage[familydefault,light]{Chivo}`
or
`\usepackage[familydefault,regular]{Chivo}`
I can only access one of them at the same time. I tried to play around with the .sty file of the font without any success.

I hope you guys can help me! I am using PdfLatex

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  maybe you could "cheat", and declare chiva regular to be the boldface font.

Comment: Is a luatex solution usable for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Barbara Beeton suggests, you could use this approach (not intensely tested, but should work for italics as well) if you have to stick to PDFLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[familydefault=true,light]{Chivo}

\makeatletter
 \def\bfseries@sf{m}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

 \lipsum[1]
 {\bfseries\lipsum[2]}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Just for completeness, this is simple to do with LuaLaTeX. To show that the correct fonts are used, I've made separate versions of the Light and Regular font for comparison. This is not needed for the actual solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Chivo}[Extension = .ttf, UprightFont = *-Light,
     BoldFont = *-Regular,
     ItalicFont = *-LightItalic,
     BoldItalicFont = *-Italic]
\newfontfamily\light{Chivo Light}
\newfontfamily\regular{Chivo Regular}
\begin{document}

This is some regular text. \emph{This is some italic text}

{\light This is some light text}

\bfseries This is bold regular text \emph{This is some bold italic text}

{\regular This is some regular text}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]